# What is the difference between predict() function and the model$predicted in case of a random forest model in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, predict

Using random forest package:-

```
#install.packages("randomForest")
library(randomForest)
```

I used an online code to run random forest on my system. I got a model with confusion matrix and accuracy etc.
Now, my data is in the form of training and validation sets. I got the data from here:-
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/
I divided it in a ratio of 70%-30% (training - validation, respectively).
Then i ran a model on it. 
The model results gave me an answer that around 30 observations were misclassified for one particular value of the variable on which the random forest was run.
Below is the sample data:-

```
     BuyingPrice Maintenance NumDoors NumPersons Bootspace Safety Condition
        vhigh         low        4          4       med    low     unacc
        vhigh         med        2          4       med   high       acc
        vhigh         med        2       more     small   high     unacc
        vhigh        high        3          4       big   high     unacc
        vhigh         med        4       more     small    med     unacc
         low         low        2       more       med    med       acc
```

The randomForest was run on predicting the last variable, "Condition".
Below is the model summary

```
Call:
 randomForest(formula = Condition ~ ., data = TrainSet, ntree = 500,      
mtry = 6, importance = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 6

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 2.48%
Confusion matrix:
      acc good unacc vgood class.error
acc   244    4     6     2  0.04687500
good    3   44     1     0  0.08333333
unacc  11    1   843     0  0.01403509
vgood   2    0     0    47  0.04081633
```

If we take the first row of the table (the one just above us), we see that the value "acc" has had 244 correct predictions (95%) and 12 wrong predictions.
Similarly, "good" has had 44 correct predictions (91%) and 4 wrong predictions. And so on for the other two.
Total number of wrong predictions are 30 (12+4+12+2)
Now, technically the predicted values of this model should differ from the actual by 30 misclassified values.
Now i tried getting the predicted values by two methods:-

```
    1. First method :- model2$predicted.
    2. Second method :- predTrain <- predict(model2, TrainSet, type = "class")
```

The First method gives me a predicted value set that differs from the actual in 30 places while the second method gives me an dataset which is exactly equal to the actual values.
I think the first method is correct but the guy in the link has used the second one.

```
 https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-implement-random-forests-in-r/
```

Not sure where my concepts are going wrong
Please help.
PS:- I know there is a similar question that has been asked but i feel that both the question and the answers below it were not sufficiently elaborate or easily explainable for me. That's why, i asked a new question.

SAMPLE CODE

```
set.seed(100)
train <- sample(nrow(data1),0.7*nrow(data1),replace=FALSE)
TrainSet <- data1[train,]
ValidSet <- data1[-train,]
model2 <- randomForest(Condition ~ ., data = TrainSet, ntree = 500, mtry=6, 
importance = TRUE)
predTrain <- predict(model2, TrainSet, type = "class")
new1 <- data.frame(actual = TrainSet$Condition, predicted = predTrain)
new2 <- data.frame(actual = TrainSet$Condition, predicted = 
model2$predicted)
new1$third <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(new1))
{
if(new1[i,1] == new1[i,2])
{
new1[i,3] = 1
}else{
new1[i,3] = 0
}
}
new2$third <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(new2))
{
  if(new2[i,1] == new2[i,2])
  {
    new2[i,3] = 1
  }else{
    new2[i,3] = 0
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Abhay

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation of randomForest function:
predicted: the predicted values of the input data based on **out-of-bag** samples.

So the predicted value of an observation is obtained with a model that does not use this observation.

The predict function applies the model learnt to new data and doesn't know they was used for training. So any observation is used for both learning and predict.

You should used the predicted output as every predicted value is computed without the corresponding observation used for training.

Comment: i understand the difference between validation and training sets. My question is, why are there two different results of predict on the training set. Shouldn'd both "model$predicted" and predict() showcase same results for the training set?

Comment: @AbhaySaini When you run the predict function, it does not know that you are using the same data as you used in training, hence it predicts using all the trees. The predicted values in the model are based only on OOB samples.